# Search Console shows 343 web pages submitted but only 132 indexed

Tags: google-search-console, search-engine-indexing

My Search Console (Webmaster Tools) account shows 343 web pages submitted but only 132 indexed. The actual number of posts on my blog are 138. What should I do?

I am also getting 179 "not found" errors; what should I do about those errors?
Any help regarding these issues would be appreciated a lot. Thanks!

Comment: Do you have an xml sitemap that you submitted? How many pages are in it?

Comment: Yes I have submitted the xml sitemap. It has 343 web pages in it and 132 are indexed.

Comment: This makes no sense. You have 343 pages in your sitemap but you say you have only 138 pages in your blog. How many pages does your site really have?

Comment: My sitemap shows 343 pages submitted and only 132 are indexed but when I go to my wordpress and check the total number of posts published on my blog they are 138. I am confused whats going on. How can my sitemap show 343 pages submitted when I have only written 138 posts on my blog

Comment: That's what you need to figure out. Start by actually *looking* at your sitemap. Do you see pages you do not expect to see?

Answer (score 1):

Since you're in WordPress, I guess you have a plugin creating your sitemap for you. Depending on which plugin it may be including Category & Tag pages in the sitemap too, which usually isn't necessary.

[image: sitemap taxonomy]

Some plugins, like "WordPress SEO by Yoast", also include users/authors in the sitemap unless disabled.

[image: sitemap users]

If you try disabling these (again, depending on your plugin) then you'll have a cleaner sitemap with fewer, more relevant pages listed. That help get those pages indexed.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, my math tells me this:

```
  132 indexed pages
+ 179 not found errors
  -----
= 311 total pages I counted

  343 pages you say
- 311 officially counted pages
  -----
=  32 pages remain
```

So this tells me that there is something going on with 32 pages that are causing them not to be indexed. Could they be pages redirecting to other pages? could it be other errors such as internal server error?

What you need to do is go over your sitemap again and remove URLs that do not return an actual web page, and make sure you have 138 valid URLs listed (1 for each post) along with other URLs that point to actual webpages.

Once you resubmit your sitemap, wait another couple of days.  While you wait, go through the errors google shows you, so you know what URLs do and do not exist.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue after changing my website CMS. But I did nothing. :)

Just keep your website clean and follow Google SEO guide. Google will update their Google Webmaster report after 1-2 months.